# date("H:i:s") show +1 time in php

Tags: php, date, timezone

Im in Asia/Jakarta timezone (UTC +7).
When i run this `date("H:i:s")`, it shows +1 time.
Example 01:00 am in GMT, so it show 09:00 which should show 08:00.

I already changed my php.ini.
It's look like this.

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = "Asia/Jakarta"
```

What should i do to make it right ?

Thank you.

Comment: Try [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: I just answered a similar question not 1 day ago.....

Comment: Thank you for your respon. We need to give timezone identifier to date_default_timezone_set function, but its become static. I want to make sure that the time is the same without the timezone identifier.

Answer (score 0):

try using date_default_timezone_set

```
<?php
echo date("H:i:s");

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta"); 
echo date("H:i:s");
?>
```

This works fine,

```
07:02:15
14:02:15
```

[see example code](http://codepad.org/0qfHCdi5)

Comment: Thank you for your respon. What if people in +8 use my web application so, it still whow my timezone's time, right ?